# Jade + Javascript no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, jade

Tengo una plantilla .jade

```
extends layoutIn

block content

    input(type="text", id="captureInput", style="width:100%")
    pre(id="resultado", style="overflow-y: scroll; height:150px")
```

y el javascript es:

```
var texto       = document.getElementById('captureInput'),
    resultado   = document.getElementById('resultado'),
    teclas      = {}; //acá guardamos tiempo de inicio y fin de cada tecla
alert("1");
texto.addEventListener('keydown', function(keyboardEvent) {
    alert("2");
    const timestamp = performance.now(),
          keyName   = keyboardEvent.key;

    if (!teclas[keyName]) { //Sólo si no se está manteniendo presionado
        teclas[keyName] = {down: timestamp};
    }
});
```

> muestra el primer alert, pero el segundo nunca.

NOTA: El mismo codigo con jquery funciona 100% con el siguiente codigo jquery funciona

```
$(function () {
            var captureInput = $('#captureInput');
            $(captureInput).focus();

                $(captureInput).keydown(function(event){ //inicio de presion
                    var timeDown = (new Date()).getTime();
                    var keyName=event.keyCode;
                    if (!teclas[keyName]) { //Sólo si no se está manteniendo presionado
                        teclas[keyName] = {down: timeDown};
                    }                     
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que funcione en cualquier navegador hay que esperar a que el objeto document esté listo para usar. Tu código javascript hay que meterlo en un evento **load**:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var texto       = document.getElementById('captureInput'),
        resultado   = document.getElementById('resultado'),
        teclas      = {}; //acá guardamos tiempo de inicio y fin de cada tecla
    alert("1");
    texto.addEventListener('keydown', function(keyboardEvent) {
        alert("2");
        const timestamp = performance.now(),
              keyName   = keyboardEvent.key;

        if (!teclas[keyName]) { //Sólo si no se está manteniendo presionado
            teclas[keyName] = {down: timestamp};
        }
    });
});
```

El uso de

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
```

equivale en jQuery a:

```
$(function () {
```

y que lo está haciendo es esperar a que el documento esté listo para usarse